# converting/parsing geojson into com.vividsolutions.jts geometry

Tags: geojson, geometry, java, geotools, jts-topology-suite

Does any has any experience with converting string geojson into com.vividsolutions.jts geometry object (point, polygon, etc). Maybe there is some java library I cannot find.

Greets!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) provides a [GeoJSON module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/geojson.html) which will read in GeoJSON files and convert them to GeoTools Feature Collections - the geometry elements of these collections is stored as a JTS object. So all you need is

```
 Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
```

Answer (score 14):

For a much more lightweight alternative to GeoTools, check out [jts2geojson](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jts2geojson):

```
GeoJSONReader reader = new GeoJSONReader();
Geometry geometry = reader.read(json);
```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be nowadays also native GeoJSON reader/writer code in JTS trunk:

https://sourceforge.net/p/jts-topo-suite/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/jtsio/src/main/java/com/vividsolutions/jts/io/geojson/

**EDIT**

OpenJUMP can read and write GeoJSON with code that is in https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/core/trunk/src/com/vividsolutions/jump/io/geojson/. Perhaps it could be reused.