# GeoJSON java library

Tags: geojson, java, json

I am creating a Java web service that receives GeoJSON.

Does anyone know a java library to manage GeoJSON?

Comment: You need to give a bit more information about what you want to do with the incoming GeoJSON.

Comment: For now only read the geometry and properties .

I know you can treat a GeoJSON as a JSON , only that I preferred to use a library to avoid errors.I was hoping that there was already instead of having to write it myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Geotools](http://www.geotools.org/) as a support for geojson. See [here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/geom/GeometryJSON.html).

Otherwise, you could simply use a typical JSON parser (such as [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)) together with [the geoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html), which is really easy to use.

The best solution depends on what you want to do with the parsed information.

Comment: Related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90041/

Answer (score 7):

To parse or deserialize geojson in Java REST webservice, i prefere to use [geojson-jackson](https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson) , which integrate itself very nicely with [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Comment: I'm trying to use that library but I can't find any documentation on how to use it. Do you know where I can find some?

Comment: yes there's no doc apart the Readme page in github, but i think that page is enough, what's you need to know to use that library ?

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is [GeoGson](https://github.com/filosganga/geogson), which is built on top of [Google's Gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
Geometry geometry = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GeometryAdapterFactory())
        .create()
        .fromJson("{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\": [23.5,20.125]}");
```

Comment: This works like a charm! It's perfectly compatible with Android as well.