# Given a GeoJSON file how do I calculate the area of the embedded features?

Tags: javascript, geojson, java, ios

We have a GeoJSON file that contains an array of features each with their associated geometry.  How can I calculate the area of each feature?  Are there any Java or Swift libraries to help me?  Any advice on how to get started here?

Please excuse the naive nature of this question.  I'm new to this GeoJSON stuff.

Comment: You could try turf.js. https://www.mapbox.com/help/intro-to-turf/#turf-area.

Comment: This post is same as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130913/geojson-java-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) is a Java library which can read and write [GeoJSON](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/geojson.html) and provides access to features like area via the [JTS library](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html). It will also help you to [reproject](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html) the geometries from the lat/lon of GeoJSON to a suitable projection for calculating areas in m^2.

Comment: I thought this was off-topic considering the ios and javascript tags but there is indeed a javascript port of GeoTools https://github.com/jillesvangurp/geotools-js.

Comment: I was doubtful too but he specifically mentions java in the question

Comment: I should have made that more clear.  I am currently trying to make the decision to do this on the back end (Java/Clojure) or on the front end (iOS and Android) and am trying to figure out the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this several ways,
I think that the easiest (if you only have a few GIS things to do) 
 is to use **Turf**
[see here](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_area.html)

There are also a couple of GIS library whom are a bit 
heavier (size wise)
**leaflet:**
[how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724725/how-to-get-the-area-string-from-a-polygon-using-leaflet-draw)

After you can also try **openlayers3**

Answer (score 0):

Some JS libraries from Mapbox:

- [mapboxgeojson-area compute the area of a geojson polygon or multipolygon - GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-area)
- [mapboxcheap-ruler Fast approximations for common geodesic measurements  - GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler)